# Creating a dictionary from specific rows of a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with data from .csv file/files

I want to iterate through .csv files and use the first row of the .csv file as keys and third row of .csv file as values.

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import collections
import operator
import functools
import os
import csv
import glob

root = "C:\\Users\\Public\\DiplomskaNaloga\\anomaly_count"

slovar_list = list()

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(root, '*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding = 'cp1252')
    slovar = df.to_dict()
    slovar_list.append(slovar)

    res = dict(functools.reduce(operator.add,
                            map(collections.Counter, napake_list)))
```

I want a dictionary created as explained above. I will append each created dictionary to a list to create a list of dictionaries and then add the values of same keys as that is what I need as an output.

The command `df.to_dict()` doesn't work for me or I am just not experienced enough to understand the doc string on how to set it up to work for me

[image]

These zeros are from the second row which is empty. I dont need that.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "doesn't work for me".  Ideally show the output you get and the output you expect.

Comment: Look at the docs for `pd.read_csv`.  There are options to skip the first row of data in the CSV file (after the header).

Comment: `pd.read_csv(file, encoding='cp1252', skiprows=[1,2], nrows=4).squeeze().to_dict()`

Comment: show expected output. Maybe you should use `df.iloc[2].to_dict()` to work only with 3rd row

Comment: these zeros are NOT values from empy row(s) but indexes (number of row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These zeros are NOT values from empty row(s) but indexes (number of row).

You should select single row using `.iloc[]` - but for your example output you should rather use index `0` instead of index `2` because it seems it skiped empty rows.

```
df.iloc[0].to_dict()
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Column X': ['A','B','C'], 
    'Column Y': ['D','E','F'], 
    'Column Z': ['G','H','I']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('--- df ---')
print(df)

print('--- all rows ---')
print(df.to_dict())

print('--- one row ---')
print(df.iloc[2].to_dict())
```

Result:

```
--- df ---
  Column X Column Y Column Z
0        A        D        G
1        B        E        H
2        C        F        I
--- all rows ---
{'Column X': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Column Y': {0: 'D', 1: 'E', 2: 'F'}, 'Column Z': {0: 'G', 1: 'H', 2: 'I'}}
--- one row ---
{'Column X': 'C', 'Column Y': 'F', 'Column Z': 'I'}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly it skips the empty row? But does it also skip this row when indexing rows?

Comment: I don't have your data. Try this code on your data and you will see if you need index `.iloc[2]` or `.iloc[0]`. Your problem is not empty rows but you use `.to_dict()` on full `pandas.DataFrame` but you have to do it on only one selected row - which will be `pandas.Series` instead of `pandas.DataFrame`